# Get result from an ActionResult directly in the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jsonresult

I want to be able to get the result that the `ActionResult` will generate directly in my controller for debugging purposes. How do I do that?

Something like:

```
public ActionResult Parts(string id)
{
    var parts = _repository.GetParts(id);
    var action = Json(parts);

    var generatedJson = XXXXX;

    return action;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For debugging purposes you definitely want to use a debugging tool such as [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), but if you insist <strike>polluting</strike>modifying your source code when in Debug mode you could take a look at the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class (which is internally used by the [JsonResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult.aspx) class):

```
var generatedJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(parts);
```

Comment: The polluting comment is unnecessary since you do not know how/why I needed it or how my code looks in general.

Comment: @jgauffin, that's correct and a good reason to have it mentioned in the question. This would have avoided such comments and maybe even proposed a different and more adapted answer to your scenario.

Comment: imho it's not relevant at all. My question is quite specific and that should be enough. I would have asked differently if I wanted alternatives. I would understand if you wanted to inform a new user that the wanted solution might not be a correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are returning Json and I assume you want to look at the result, you can use a json viewer plugin in FireFox, [jsonview](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/jsonview/). At least that's how I do it.

In case it's for some other reason, please specify what you want to do exactly.

Comment: No. I want to get the json as a string in the controller

Answer (score 0):

Call ExecuteResult on the result.

But if you want to inspect the json returned by it, use the browser debugging tools along with some json viewer add-on.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use something like NLog and bind it to ILogger in your global.asax. thereafter, you can temporarily send any json related controller actions out to the log file for later inspection.

another way is to use an actionfilter and decorate the action that you wanna capture (these could be saved in a log file or some other visual rendering device). there's a good example of this that you could adapt for your purposes here:

http://binary-studio.com/blog/technical-blog/asp-net-mvc-custom-action-filters/

hope this helps..